# Uncaught ReferenceError: check_url is not defined

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I've just picked up a project that had a ton of javascript issues, and I have been able to resolve all of them except the following. When pages in this site load, I continually receive the following error in the Chrome console.

**"Uncaught ReferenceError: check_url is not defined"**

[image]

I've searched the entire solution for "check_url" and that combination of letters does not exist anywhere, even in the third party files that I am including (jQuery, jQuery Mobile).

Could this have something to do with the fact that I am using the Application Cache to cache my pages?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you can't find where *check_url* is being called?

Comment: Did you try checking in the HTML pages, there is a chance that it might be added in pages onLoad or any other elements click,.. events.

Comment: It could be a chrome extensison you should clear your cache also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Workforce and @meda. They were both right in that a Chrome extension was actually the root of the JavaScript error. I recently installed the Music Plus for Google Play extension and that is the culprit.
[image]

Thanks again for all of your help!